# Python list with multiple 2D list append same value to first row of each value

Tags: list, python-2.7, matrix, 2d

I have a list like this:

```
a = [[[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

Which means i have two 2D list inside a list:

```
a[0] = [0, 1], [1, 1]           

a[1] = [1, 0], [1, 1]
```

and i would like to append the same value to the first and second row (let's say [0, 1]) for both 2D list at the same time; resulting in something like this:

```
a[0] = [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]           


a[1] = [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]
```

i don't want to do it becuase i am trying to improve the time spent in loops.

I have been doing it this way:

```
        elif (rown == 0) and (columnn > 0):
            s_routine = time.time()
            p_temp = p[:]
            p = []
            for matrix in p_temp:
                ca = matrix[0][columnn]
                cb = matrix[1][columnn]
                if columnv == 0:
                    zl = zfc[str(ca)+str(cb)]
                    for z in zl:
                        a = matrix[0] + [z[0][1]]
                        b = matrix[1] + [z[1][1]]
                        c = [a, b]
                        p.append(c)
                elif columnv == 1:
                    ol = zfc[str(ca)+str(cb)]
                    for o in ol:
                        a = matrix[0] + [o[0][1]]
                        b = matrix[1] + [o[1][1]]
                        c = [a, b]
                        p.append(c)
            e_routine = time.time() - s_routine
```

But the matrix is growing too much and therefore the loops are taking a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this easier, for example:

```py
a = [[[0, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]]]

for row in a:
    for subl, v in zip(row, [0, 1]):
        subl.append(v)

print(a)
```

Prints:

```
[[[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]]
```

Comment: How is it going to behave when the list grows more and more? then loops are ging to kill the time performance.

Comment: @Mayobanex I don't understand, you're looping over rows in your matrix, that's constant. Appending a value to the end of list is constant (O(1)) too.

Comment: I will post my full code in next answer so you can have a better idea of what is the problem i am facing.

Comment: I just noticed that my issue is that i am growing a list with matrix on it, there's no possible way to control the time it will take because the larget the input matrix the most it will take to calculate... i tried using zip to iterate in parallel but i noticed that iterating 3 variables in parallel using zip is the same time as doing each one after the other.... anyways, your inout gave me good ideas and new things to learn!